# Django:The value of id is coming None when adding new profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have the below models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
    name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True)
    permanant_address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    subscribed_products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='products_subscribed',blank=True)
```

The profile is created by the below signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(name=instance)
```

When I add a new user it doesnot creates a new profile and when I try to add profile manually the value of the primary key field is coming `None`..

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Whose primary key is None? instance.pk? Can you show full error message?

Comment: There is no error message.. When i try to add a profile from admin the value if `id` is coming `None` and it gets deleted automatically

Comment: `gets deleted automatically` how is that? Whose id is None? Your model `Profile` has default primary key field `id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` (because you did not specify anything explicitly) which is auto-incremented and does not need any input.

Comment: The auto generated `id` of profile model is coming `None`

Comment: Please show your code which is expecting this id and how you're determining that it is None.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari this would produce dups.

Comment: @IvanStarostin agree